# How can I set different build type for each build variant

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-build-type

I have a two flavor for my app. This two flavor use different baseurl. I have 4 url totally.

**admintest**

**adminrelease**

**usertest**

**userrelease**

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {
        debug{   //baseurl for debug   }
        release{   //baseurl for release   }
    }
    // Specifies one flavor dimension.
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        user {

        }
        admin {

        }
    }
}
```

I only set one url in debug and relase now and I cant find how can I set url for each flavor.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: why not put your URL in `strings.xml` . you can create separate `string.xml`for each flavor.

Comment: each flavor use same strings.xml , I cannot divide

Comment: nope. you can create separate `string.xml`

Answer (score 2):

You can see in below image i have flavors of my app

> src >> main

is used as common for all.

> src >> flavorVersionTwo

here i created separate `strings.xml` which will overwrite the main `strings.xml` for same string_name.

**Example**

lets suppose you have `base_url` string  in `src >> main >> strings.xml`

when you are using (in my case) falvorVersionTwo.

if you added `base_url` string in `src >> flavorVersionTwo >> strings.xml` then it will overwrite the `base_url` written in main->strings.xml.

[image]

**Note:**

For more understanding you can Read [this](https://www.androidauthority.com/building-multiple-flavors-android-app-706436/) and [this](https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-1-building-white-label-apps-on-android-ade16af23bcf)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like following code snippet:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {
        debug{   buildConfigField "String", "MY_URL", "https://debug"   }
        release{   buildConfigField "String", "MY_URL", "https://release"   }
    }
    // Specifies one flavor dimension.
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        user {

        }
        admin {

        }
    }
}
```

After edit your build.gradle file,you need sync it.

After sync complete,you can use MY_URL by `BuildConfig.MY_URL`(`BuildConfig` is generated by Gradle automatically),it looks like following picture:

[image]

If your buildType is release then BuildConfig.MY_URL's value will be `https://release` or debug then it will be `https://debug`