# Gradle - Android - buildConfigField base on a pair of (productFlavors, buildTypes)

Tags: android, gradle, android-build-flavors, android-build-type, android-buildconfig

I have a field YOUR_POWER which is set to a value based on the BuildType.

My config in `build.gradle`:

```
productFlavors{
    free {
        buildConfigField "int", "YOUR_POWER", 80
    }
    paid {
        buildConfigField "int", "YOUR_POWER", 100
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {}
    release {}
}
```

How can I have some config like: `free + debug = power 70`; `free + release = power 80`; `paid + debug = power 90` and `paid + release = power 100` ?

Any suggestion/alternative solution are welcome :)

@updated: this is just an example, the field type can be String too.

same question: [How can I set different build type for each build variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53185968/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use 2 values:

```
productFlavors{
    free {
        buildConfigField "int", "YOUR_POWER_BASE", 70
    }
    paid {
        buildConfigField "int", "YOUR_POWER_BASE", 90
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "int", "YOUR_POWER_INCREASER", 0
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "int", "YOUR_POWER_INCREASER", 10
    }
}
```

And create a sum of them in the code:

```
val yourPower = BuildConfig.YOUR_POWER_BASE + BuildConfig.YOUR_POWER_INCREASER
```

Comment: thank you Luca, your idea is really good for `int` but it doesnt work with `String` type :(

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30486355/6439023)'s the solution then :)

Comment: thanks, it is really nice to have your suggestion, but i have kind of 10 flavors with 4 build types, moreover this is hard to update later :(

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution is to use sourceset

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourceset-build

You can create a xml file eg: config.xml which can vary by [variant, build type]